# How do i do this in Linq?

Tags: .net, linq, json

i've got an `IList<Foo>` and I'm trying to serialize it as `Json` without the field names included in the result. As such, i'm trying to create an *anonymous object*, which i pass to the Json serialization method.

Foo is defined as (pseudo code):-

```
public class Foo
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

When i return this as Json ...

```
return Json(foos);
```

the result is like

```
... [{"X":1,"Y":2},{"X":3,"Y":4}...]
```

I don't want the X and Y to be there. So i'm after..

```
... [{1,2},{3,4}...]
```

So i was trying to do the following (which doesn't work)

```
(from p in foos
 select new p.X + "," + p.Y).ToArray()
```

or

```
(from p in foos
 select new string(p.X+ "," + p.Y)).ToArray()
```

but to no avail (doesn't compile).

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(from p in foos
 select String.Format("{{{0}, {1}}}", p.X, p.Y)).ToArray()
```

Comment: God, Linq is beautifully elegant and powerful.

Answer (score 5):

```
foos.Select(p=>p.X + "," + p.Y)
```

Or if you perfer Linq Syntax:

```
(from p in foos
 select p.X + "," + p.Y).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a member serializer, and uses the names. If you don't want names, don't use JSON. Perhaps just `StringBuilder`, then?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
foreach(var foo in items) {
  sb.Append('{').Append(foo.X).Append(',').Append(foo.Y).Append("},");
}
sb[sb.Length - 1] = ']';
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: LINQ is a tool. Just a tool. It isn't the answer to every problem.

Comment: true .. but i find i make my code a lot more readable with some succinct linq queries.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the JSON string yourself, so you have complete control over how it is set up rather than using the Serialization method.